# Add each element of an array after each element of another array php

Tags: php, arrays

I've got 2 arrays.

I would like to add each element in array2 after each element in array1.

Could you please help me how to figure out this in PHP.

```
Array1[] = ("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4");
Array2[] = ("ADD1","ADD2","ADD3","ADD4");
FinalArray[] =("Test1","ADD1","Test2","ADD2","Test3","ADD3","Test4","ADD4");
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far in php? Please show your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `foreach`

```
$Array1 = array("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4");
$Array2 = array("ADD1","ADD2","ADD3","ADD4");

foreach ($Array1 as $key => $value) {
    $FinalArray[] = $value;
    if(isset($Array2[$key]))
        $FinalArray[] = $Array2[$key];
}
print_r($FinalArray);
```

[See the result](https://eval.in/834378)

Comment: Thanks very much that works for me. Even though I posted an eg. I only thought about updating Array1 and not creating a new array with all the elements. Thanks Desai for your help.Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$Array1 = array("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4");
$Array2 = array("ADD1","ADD2","ADD3","ADD4");

for($i=0 ;$i<count($Array1);$i++ ){

$a[] = $Array1[$i];
$a[] = $Array2[$i];

}

print_r($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This Code:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4");
$arr2 = array("ADD1","ADD2","ADD3","ADD4");
$final_arr = array();
$index1=0;
$index2=0;
for($i=1;$i<=count($arr1)+count($arr2);$i++)
{
    if($i%2==0)
    {
      array_push($final_arr,$arr2[$index2]);
      $index2++;
    }
    else
    {
      array_push($final_arr,$arr1[$index1]);
      $index1++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$k=0;
$j=0;
$final_arr = array();
for($i=1;$i<=count($arr1);$i++)
{
    if($i%2!=0)
    {
       array_push($final_arr,$arr1[$k]);
       $k++;
    }
    else
    {
       array_push($final_arr,$arr2[$j]);
       $j++;
    }
}
```